# jenkins pipeline quits after sh

Tags: jenkins

In Jenkins, i have a pipleline build, that is not sandboxed. I have this directory structure that I am trying to traverse and do a npm publish, But I think the loop, nor the npm has anything to do with my problem.

Jenkis seems to be simply exiting (cleanly) after my "sh" script. For instance, I have this:

```
echo "Starting scripts"
sh "cd ${directory}/; npm version 1.0.${version}; npm publish --registry http://artifactorypro.me.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm/; cd ..; "
echo "Finished"
```

And what happens is that in the console output,  I see the "Starting scripts"  and the artifact gets properly published,  but I do NOT see the "Finished" echo, and the build exits cleanly. I can even break it down to this:

```
echo "Starting scripts"
sh "cd ${directory}/;"
echo "In direcotry"
sh "npm version 1.0.${version}; npm publish --registry http://artifactorypro.me.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm/;"
echo "artifact published"
sh "cd ../..; "
echo "Finished"
```

and I get the "starting scripts" then "+ cd mydirectory/"  but no "In directory"  This is all in a loop the I know the length > 1 but it never gets to it.  It just quits after the first "sh"

What's happening here?

Comment: why do you need the semi-colon at the end of the command? I understand for connecting different commands but why at the end?

Comment: I guess I don't,  but it did not change anything.

Comment: Can you remove those and try again?

Comment: I read somewhere that semicolons can also be used as terminators to commands invoked by exec

Comment: I removed the last semicolon, and it still did not work.  Like I said in the question, after the first "sh"  the script just exits without error, and does not execute any line after.

Answer (score 0):

As shown here, you could chain multiple commands in a sh step with:

- `&&`: `sh "cd ${directory}/ && echo "In directory" && npm version ..."`
- `sh '''`

The last one is more readable:

```
sh """         cd ${directory}/
         npm version 1.0.${version}
         npm publish --registry http://artifactorypro.me.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm/ 
         cd ..
"""
```